# Oпределение номера блока jQuery

Tags: jquery

как на jquery определить на каком data-id кликнул пользователь

```
<div data-id='1'>1</div>
<div data-id='2'>2</div>
<div data-id='3'>3</div>
<div data-id='4'>4</div>
```

допустим есть такие блоки как определить номер дата

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').on('click', function(){

    console.log($(this).index()); // получим позицию дива, начиная с нуля. т.е. если кликнули по data-id='3' - получим 2

    console.log($(this).data('id')); // получим то что находится в data-id, т.е. если нажали по data-id='3' - получим 3
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('div').data('id'));
console.log($('div').eq(3).data('id'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bXmP/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function () {
if ($(this).attr('data-id') !== '') {
console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
}});
```

Так намного удобнее

Comment: @HappyCougar, и чем же?

Comment: если уж используется data-*, лучше использовать метод .data()

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(
    function(e){
    $('div').removeClass('active');//удаляем для всех классов
    $(this).addClass('active');// для накрытово дива добавляем класс

        var idSite = $('.active').attr('data-id'); //получаем айди сайта
        alert(idSite);

});
```